# How to hide content with ng-if and a checkbox that's inside a ng-repeat and it's ng-model is an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I have a list of checkboxes that are created using a ng-repeat, I use those checkboxes to get the IDs of the objects that are inside a list, these objects have a name property and a id property. 
this is a object inside my categoryList

```
category = {
   idCategory: 2,
   name: 'myName'
};
```

And this is how I declare my checkboxes.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select a category</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="idsCategory[category.idCategory]"> {{category.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

and then in my controller I get the ids like this

```
var categories= $scope.categoryList;

var idsSelected = [];


//get selected ids
for (var idCategory in categories) {
    if (categories.hasOwnProperty(idCategory )) {
        if (categories[idCategory ] === true) {

            idsSelected .push(idCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

but now I want to hide and show some inputs in my HTML, if the user selects a category like "support" I want to show some inputs, but I don't know what condition put inside my ng-if since I declare my checkboxes ng-model like an array of ids like this `ng-model="idsCategory[category.idCategory]"`

how can I put my ng-if to hide the inputs I tried this but this doesn't work

```
<div id="b" ng-if="idsCategory.category.name=='Support'">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Support hours:</label>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="support houres">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

If we have HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select a category</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="idsCategory[category.idCategory]"> {{category.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Conroller:

```
$scope.idsCategory = {};
$scope.categoryList = [{
    idCategory: 1,
    name: 'categoryA'
}, {
    idCategory: 2,
    name: 'recreation'
}, {
    idCategory: 3,
    name: 'develop'
}, {
    idCategory: 4,
    name: 'Support'
}];
```

Then we can use following `ng-show`:

```
<div id="b" ng-show="idsCategory[4]">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Support hours:</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="support houres">
    </div>
</div>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcosp58u/)

In checkbox input we have `ng-model="idsCategory[category.idCategory]"`, so `idsCategory[4]` stores info if category with `idCategory = 4` is checked. That's why element  with `ng-show="idsCategory[4]"` will be shown if category with `idCategory = 4` is checked.

Comment: is not working and I think that is because  my ng-model is declared like this `ng-model="idsCategory[category.idCategory] `  I think that if I delcared it like I'm actually declaring a list of numeric values

Comment: If you need help with that, prepare jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: I don't know how to use jsfiddle but I created an account in the site, and I tried to re create my code but I'm getting the error that says that my app is not defined https://jsfiddle.net/jsfengfid/1qdhdbpk/16/